# Are projects under NDA not allowed in portfolio?

Tags: portfolio

I've been doing freelance jobs lately that do not involve NDA. However I received an offer from a client that requires an NDA prior to project start. Does NDA projects restrict the project themselves from being put in my portfolio?

Comment: Check if the NDA covers silence only until the release or it says something like "6 months after release blahblah". If the product is released, you may putit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much depends on the content of the NDA.

Recently, I worked on a cutting-edge mobile payment app - and even without an NDA, it was pretty obvious that I (initially) was not allowed to mention it. However, after the launch, I could mention the project by name and elaborate on the technology stack.

Whenever in doubt, just ask the client. I usually send a sample description for them to approve, as that seems a simple and transparent way to avoid any legal pitfalls.

Answer (score 5):

Uhm, **YES**. They are *not* allowed.

**Non-Disclosure** means you can't tell anyone what you worked on. That includes showing it off in a portfolio.

If you would like to display the work in your portfolio you need to **specifically** discuss that with the client and get an *written addendum* to the NDA which specifically states what you *can* display in a portfolio. But I can't see any clients being okay with *"Keep our secrets... but show them off in a portfolio".*

Comment: The NDA may, or may not, have a specific time frame that covers what can be disclosed. Reading the specific NDA is the only way to know as it can go either way.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the NDA. NDA's I sign generally concern information I will receive or process in the course of the project, but that doesn't mean I can't put the project on my resume.

And when in doubt: just ask the client.